# Extract words from strings without spaces or delimiters using R

Tags: r

- babybag - baby bag
- badshelter - bad shelter
- themoderncornerstore - the modern corner store
- hamptonfamilyguidebook - hampton family guide book

Is there a way to use R to extract words from string that do not have spaces or other delimiters? I have a list of URLs and I am trying to figure out what words are included in the URLs.

```
input <- c("babybag", "badshelter", "themoderncornerstore", "hamptonfamilyguidebook")
```

Comment: it's in principle possible starting from a given dictionary but there could be ambiguous cases, what about "cornerstone" for example ? or what about if some part of the url is not an existing word ?

Comment: how do you determine the word break. eg. `Therestat` is it the rest at or there stat??? you must define a splitting point

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper got it. how would the dictionary approach work?

Comment: @Onyambu unfortunately there is no delimiters at all to determine breakpoints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a naive approach that might give you inspiration, I used library `hunspell` but you could test substrings against any dictionary.

I start from the right, try every substring and keep the longest I can find in the dictionary, then change my starting position, it's quite slow so I hope you don't have 4 millions of those. `hampton` is not in this dictionary so it doesn't give the right result for the last one :

```
split_words <- function(x){
  candidate <- x
  words <- NULL
  j <- nchar(x)
  while(j !=0){
    word <- NULL
    for (i in j:1){
      candidate <- substr(x,i,j)
      if(!length(hunspell::hunspell_find(candidate)[[1]])) word <- candidate
    }
    if(is.null(word)) return("")
    words <- c(word,words)
    j <- j-nchar(word)
  }
  words
}


input <- c("babybag", "badshelter", "themoderncornerstore", "hamptonfamilyguidebook")

lapply(input,split_words)
# [[1]]
# [1] "baby" "bag" 
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "bad"     "shelter"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "the"    "modern" "corner" "store" 
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "h"         "amp"       "ton"       "family"    "guidebook"
#
```

Here's a quick fix, adding words manually to the dictionary:

```
split_words <- function(x, additional = c("hampton","otherwordstoadd")){
  candidate <- x
  words <- NULL
  j <- nchar(x)
  while(j !=0){
    word <- NULL
    for (i in j:1){
      candidate <- substr(x,i,j)
      if(!length(hunspell::hunspell_find(candidate,ignore = additional)[[1]])) word <- candidate
    }
    if(is.null(word)) return("")
    words <- c(word,words)
    j <- j-nchar(word)
  }
  words
}


input <- c("babybag", "badshelter", "themoderncornerstore", "hamptonfamilyguidebook")

lapply(input,split_words)
# [[1]]
# [1] "baby" "bag" 
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "bad"     "shelter"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "the"    "modern" "corner" "store" 
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "hampton"   "family"    "guidebook"
#
```

You can just cross fingers not to have any ambiguous expressions though. Note that `"guidebook"` is in one word in my output so we already have an edge case in your four examples.

Comment: thanks so much! I'll give it a try and see how it works.

Comment: any idea why I would get this error: Error in nchar(word) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: do you get it on the sample data or only on your real data ?

Comment: it worked on the sample data. I tried to apply it to the real data using `input<-df$search` and that is when the error occurs

Comment: type `print(x)` as the first line of the function, and tell me what is the last printed string before it crashes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177054/discussion-between-ryan-praskievicz-and-moody-mudskipper).